# adding subdocuments in a mongodb document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm working on this Node.js app and I'm finding some difficulties in dealing with arrays and subdocumnts in my MongoDb databse.

I need to add so many subdocuments and in that form, it can't. Any help ?

This is my model file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//schéma d'u devis
var productDevisSchema = new Schema({       
    article : String,
    marque : String,
    qte : Number,
    budget : Number,            
});

var devisSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    description : String,
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    createEnd: {type: Date},
    state : Boolean,
    userid: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'Provider'},
    appelOffreid: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'AppelOffre'},
    productdevis: [productDevisSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Devis', devisSchema);
```

and this is my controller function:

```
exports.createDevis = function(req, res){
    var devis = new Devis({
        title : req.body.title,
        description : req.body.description,
        createEnd: req.body.createEnd,
        state : req.body.state,
        userid: req.body.userid,
        appelOffreid : req.body.appelOffreid,

        productdevis: [{
            article : req.body.article,
            marque : req.body.marque,
            qte : req.body.qte,
            budget : req.body.budget,
        }]
    });

    devis.save(function(err){
        if (err){
            return res.send(err);
        }

        res.send({message :'Devis ajoutée'});
    });
}
```